# JAVA,how can I loop my code

Tags: java

I'm first time here, please don't judge me)

Can me anybody help und say which statement I must use so my code to main question come back? ( see Code )

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What is your name? "); // Line A

        String name = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Entered name: " + name);
        System.out.println();


        switch (name) {
            case "Sam":
                System.out.println("aaa!");
                break;      // from here it must to Line A
            case "Michael":
                System.out.println("bbb!");
                break;      // from here it must to Line A      
            case "Arnold":
                System.out.println("ccc!");
                break;      // from here it must to Line A  
            default:
                System.out.println("Try again!");
       }
   }    /* and when it executes 3 times with correct answer, 
          it must go to the final line approx."Thank you" */
}
```

Comment: How would you normally make an endless loop? Did you try that here? What happened, why didn't it work?

Comment: Maybe, search for iterator in java and try implementing each one by one to find what works for you.

Comment: if you want an endless loop, just type while(true){}, and everything between the {} will loop forever, you can exit by typing break; You should have the break in an if statement, or some other kind of condition, because if it isn't then the while means nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to add an indexing integer that will increase with each correct answer, possibly do something like this

```
  public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int correctAnswers = 0;
    /*This a is called a Do-While loop and will execute the code inside once         
    *before checking the boolean statement
    */
    do{ 
        System.out.println("What is your name?"); //Line A
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Entered name: " + name + "\n");
        //Removed printing empty line and replaced with new line character

        switch (name){
            case "Sam":
                 System.out.println("aaa");
               correctAnswers++;
                  break;      // From here it repeats back to line A
              case "Michael":
                  System.out.println("bbb!");
                  correctAnswers++;
                  break;      // From here it repeats back to line A        
              case "Arnold":
                  System.out.println("ccc!");
                  correctAnswers++;
                  break;      // From here it repeats back to line A   
              default:
                  System.out.println("Try again!");
         }
    } while (correctAnswers < 3);
    System.out.println("Thank you");
  }
}
```

This code uses a do while loop which will repeat the code inside of it once, before checking whether the boolean statement is true or false. If it is true, the code will repeat, and if it is false, the code will not repeat. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Great! Thx ! But " int correctAnswers = 0; " ))